# Complex object comparison in C#

Tags: c#

I have two complex objects of the same type. I want to compare both the objects to determine if they have the exact same values. What is the efficient way of doing this ?

sample class structure given below:

```
class Package
{
    public List<GroupList> groupList;
}
class GroupList
{
   public List<Feature> featurelist;
}
class Feature
{
   public int qty;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of having the exact same values.

Comment: And which of the objects you want to compare.

Comment: with the sample class above:
compare two package objects to ensure they have the same grouplists and each grouplist has the same set of featurelist and each feature has the same value for qty.

Comment: To clarify what Ben means. Presumably (and note that this is already pure guesswork), you want two packages to be equal if they contain the same grouplists, and you want grouplists to be equal if they contain the same features, and you want features to be equal if the values of their `qty` field are equal. Now, what about ordering? If package P1 contains grouplists G1 and G2, and package P2 contains grouplists G3 and G4, and G1=G4 and G2=G3 (but G1!=G3 and G2!=G4), then are they equal or not?

Comment: order does not matter. Even if they are ordered differently, they can be considered equal

Comment: order would matter in terms of comparison. If one package contains grouplists G1, G2, and G3 in the order 1,3,2 and the second package contains the same in the order 2,1,3, then iterative comparison would be more difficult, or at least more expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so you want deep unordered structural comparison. The "unordered" part is tricky, and in fact it is a strong hint that your classes are not designed right: `List<T>` is inherently ordered, so perhaps you would rather want to use a `HashSet<T>` there (if you don't expect to have any duplicates). Doing so would make the comparison both easier to implement, and faster (though insertions would be slower):

```
class Package
{
    public HashSet<GroupList> groupList;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        Package p = o as Package;
        if (p == null) return false;
        return groupList.SetEquals(p.groupList);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return groupList.Aggregate(0, (hash, g) => hash ^ g.GetHashCode());
    }
}

class GroupList
{
   public HashSet<Feature> featureList;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        GroupList g = o as GroupList;
        if (g == null) return false;
        return featureList.SetEquals(g.featureList);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return featureList.Aggregate(0, (hash, f) => hash ^ f.GetHashCode());
    }
}

class Feature
{
    public int qty;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        Feature f = o as Feature;
        if (f == null) return false;
        return qty == f.qty;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return qty.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you want to keep using `List<T>`, you'll need to use LINQ set operations - note, however, that those are significantly slower:

```
class Package
{
    public List<GroupList> groupList;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        Package p = o as Package;
        if (p == null) return false;
        return !groupList.Except(p.groupList).Any();
    }
}

class GroupList
{
   public List<Feature> featureList;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        GroupList g = o as GroupList;
        if (g == null) return false;
        return !featureList.Except(f.featureList).Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can probably simplify the first example further by using `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer()` - you will get `GetHashCode()` on sets for free that way. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I believe you should replace the first example with `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer()` since its better to use the built in solution here. Also one should always override `GetHashCode` when overriding Equals, so code or a word on it would be better (in the 2nd example).

Answer (score 2):

For complex objects, I would consider operator overloading.

On the overloaded operator, I would define my condition for equality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We always just end up writing a method on the class that goes through everything and compares it.  You could implement this as IComparable, or override Equals.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment said, depends on how "exact" you want to measure.

You could just override equality and implement a GetHashCode method, however this does not guarantee they are exact matches. Will however ensure they are "very likely" an exact match.

Next thing you could do, is to go through every property/field in the class and compare those hash values. This would be "extremely likely" an exact match.

And to truly get an exact match, you have to compare every field and member in a recursive loop...not recommended.

Comment: I want to make sure both the objects are exact match only

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would implement the IComparable Interface on the two types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

From there you can use .CompareTo, and implement the exact comparisons required under your circumstances. This is a general best practice within .NET and I think applies well to your case.

Comment: `IComparable` is intended to be used when there is a well-defined _ordering_ on the types (i.e. when you can say that `A is less than B` and `B is greater than A`). This isn't always the case, and it isn't even required in majority of cases - normally you just want to know if `A is equal to B`. There's no need for an interface for that - `Object.Equals()` handles this case already (though there's also `IEquatable<T>`).

Comment: ... to quote the very first sentence in documentation for `IComparable`: "Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value type or class implements to __order or sort__ its instances."

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you what you want to do with comparison. Like others have pointed out IComparer is a good choice. If you are planning on using lambdas and LINQ, I would go with IEqualityComparer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx

Comment: +1 for mentioning IEqualityComparer. You can just derive from EqualityComparer<T> and override Equals & GethashCode methods.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need a method to check the two, regardless of whether or not you overload equals, or use IComparer.

You asked how to do it most efficiently, here are some tips:

- Your equality method should try to give up quickly, e.g. check if the size of the lists are the same, if they are not then return false right away
- If you could implement an efficient hashCode, you could compare the hashes first, if they are not equal then the objects are not equal, if they are equal, then you need to compare the objects to see if the objects are equal

So in general, do the fastest comparisons first to try to return false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat simplified way to do it, using reflection. You will probably need to add other checks of datatypes for specific comparisons or loop through lists etc, but this should get you started.

```
void Mymethod(){

Class1 class1 = new Class1();

//define properties for class1

Class1 class2 = new Class1();
//define properties for class2

PropertyInfo[] properties = class1.GetType().GetProperties();

bool bClassesEqual = true;

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name.ToString());

    if (property.GetValue(class1, null) != property.GetValue(class2, null))
    {
        bClassesEqual = false;
        break;

    }

}
```

}